# How to check that print was called in a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, python-unittest

Suppose `f` conditionally calls `print`; I'd like to know whether this happens within `test_*()`. How can this be accomplished?

---

**Example**:

```py
def f(integer):  # defined in and imported from separate module
    if isinstance(integer, str):
        print("WARNING: integer is str")

def test_f():
    f("5")
    assert print.called
```

---

**Attempted approach**:

```py
def tracked_call(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.called = True
    self.__call__(*args, **kwargs)

print.__call__ = tracked_call
```

```py
>>> AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object attribute '__call__' is read-only
```

Comment: Here are the docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/2.8.7/capture.html#accessing-captured-output-from-a-test-function

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38159765/mocking-a-standard-library-function-with-and-without-pytest-mock help?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thanks for linking; the answer as-is doesn't do it, but I'll read through the docs it links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1 (best)**: check that `print` was called, *and* that it prints specific text; doesn't use a fixture:

```py
import builtins
import contextlib, io
from unittest.mock import Mock

def test_f():
    mock = Mock()
    mock.side_effect = print  # ensure actual print is called to capture its txt
    print_original = print
    builtins.print = mock

    try:
        str_io = io.StringIO()
        with contextlib.redirect_stdout(str_io):
            f("5")
        output = str_io.getvalue()

        assert print.called  # `called` is a Mock attribute
        assert output.startswith("WARNING:")
    finally:
        builtins.print = print_original  # ensure print is "unmocked"
```

(If `print` in `f` writes to `sys.stderr` instead of the default `sys.stdout`, use `contextlib.redirect_stderr`.)

---

**Solution 2**: check that `print` prints specific text within call; from [docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/2.8.7/capture.html#accessing-captured-output-from-a-test-function):

```py
def test_f(capsys):
    f("5")
    out, err = capsys.readouterr()
    assert out.startswith("WARNING:")
```

This assuming the default `print(file=sys.stdout)`, else the string of interest is in `err`. If specific text is of no interest, can do `assert out or err` to verify that *something* was printed. This doesn't necessarily test whether `print` *was called*, as we can do `print(end='')`.